# WLSplashview.m location in Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I want to do add some animations with splash screen in *IBM MobileFirst Worklight* project for iOS. But I cant find "WLSplashview.m" in *Xcode Project*.

[image]

I checked with the *IBM Worklight* framework also but unable to find it.

Where can I find "WLSplashView.m" file in *Xcode Project*?

Answer (score 0):

That is not where you manage the splash screen.

By default, iOS hybrid applications show a splash screen image during application initialization. This image is selected at run time from the launch images that are supplied in the application Xcode project.

The code that shows the splash screen is in the `{AppName}.m` class in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. You can use the `[[WL.sharedInstance] showSplashScreen]` API to show the splash screen.

You must define a root view controller before you call this API. For example:

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {   ...
>
>     UIViewController* rootViewController = ...   [self.window
>     setRootViewController:rootViewController];     ...   [[WL
>     sharedInstance] showSplashScreen];   ... }

That is where you then handle your custom splash. See more here:

- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_splash_screen_ios.html
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen

Comment: In CDVSplashscreen.h file they handle the splash screen customizations ( setting imageview with image based on device width). But in IBM they are handeling with WLSplashview file (please refer screenshot). They are not using cordova Splash screen. So I want the location of the CDVSplashscreen.m where i can do some customizations (adding animations).

Comment: That's right. Please follow what IBM states in their documentation.